Manga/Manhwa/etc where the main character accidentally trapped a goddess in his phone
I remember this story I read a while back. Not sure if it was a manhwa, manga or manhua, but the main plot revolved around the main character who is a shut in, who accidentally trapped a goddess in his phone. His mother was a shaman and he was a coder of some kind. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Here is some more info of the story from what I remember (but this may or may not be 100% accurate because I read it back in early 2020). Firstly, I remember something about how technology absorbs spiritual entities but he's the first person to ever do it, and later on he also manages to trap a demon in another phone. His mother is knowledgeable of the spirits and gods and such, and I think there were some references to IRL mythology. I read up to around chapter 50 I think and the art and writing kinda reminded me a bit of "The Gamer". I think I remember him using some sort of Spirit Gun-esque attack using the phone. This is all for now, if I remember anything else, I'll edit it in

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
